# auto-indent in nano not working while writing java files

Tags: java, macos, nano

I put `set auto-indent` in ~/.nanorc
but auto-indent still not work. typing `nano lol.java`:

```
public class lol {
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
}
```

I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nano is a very simple editor, and doesn't have language-specific syntax features. The `autoindent` setting (note, no hyphen) is described in the [nano settings documentation](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Settings):

> Automatically indent a newly created line to the same number of tabs and/or spaces as the previous line (or as the next line if the previous line is the beginning of a paragraph).

So the indentation is only applied when the previous line is already indented. It does not add indentation based on blocks identified by curly braces in Java.